# Eliminating noise from sensor readings on CC3200?

Tags: filter, webserver, client, noise

step by step what I did so far

1) micro controller used CC3200 from Texas instruments ( wifi builted micro controller)
2) Conductive rubber cord stretch sensor - connected to Microcontroller's analog pin
    **Sensor's behaviour = ( resistance increases upon stretching the conductive rubber)

So now, following is the code fo reference which I debugged in to the microcontroller to run the sensor(Using energia tool-IDE).
The code is nothing but written for the web server( which I gave- available wifi ssid and password-which you can see in the following programm "iPhone and the passowrd"), where the sensor's code is also wrote in to,

And this webserver reads and generates IP address of the microcontroller and also values of the stretch sensor.

Webserver code :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>
// which analog pin to connect
#define RUBBERPIN A3

// how many samples to take and average, more takes longer
// but is more 'smooth'
#define NUMSAMPLES 5
// the value of the 'other' resistor
#define SERIESRESISTOR 10000
int samples[NUMSAMPLES];

// your network name also called SSID
char ssid[] = "iPhone";
// your network password
char password[] = "123456789";
// your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;

WiFiServer server(3000);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);      // initialize serial communication
analogReference(EXTERNAL);
pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode

// attempt to connect to Wifi network:
Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
// print the network name (SSID);
Serial.println(ssid); 
// Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP      
network:
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
// print dots while we wait to connect
Serial.print(".");
delay(300);
 }

 Serial.println("\nYou're connected to the network");
 Serial.println("Waiting for an ip address");

  while (WiFi.localIP() == INADDR_NONE) {
 // print dots while we wait for an ip addresss
 Serial.print(".");
 delay(300);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the status  
   printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("Starting dataerver on port 3000");
  server.begin();                           // start the web server on port        
  80
  Serial.println("Dataserver started!");

  }


void loop() {
// listen for incoming clients
WiFiClient client = server.available();
if (client) {
Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
  uint8_t i;
float average;
// take N samples in a row, with a slight delay
for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
samples[i] = analogRead(RUBBERPIN);
delay(10);
}
// average all the samples out
average = 0;
for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
average += samples[i];
}
average /= NUMSAMPLES;
Serial.println(average);

  client.println(average);
  delay(10);
}
delay(1);
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disonnected");
 }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
// print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
Serial.print("Network Name: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

// print your WiFi shield's IP address:
IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
Serial.print("IP Address: ");
Serial.println(ip);

// print the received signal strength:
long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
Serial.print(rssi);
Serial.println(" dBm");
  }
```

After running this programm it generates IP address and sensor's values(

221.40

221.20

221.20

*********here = value missing were a noise is visible on graph

221.00

221.20

221.40

221.00

221.20

221.40

221.00

221.40

221.20

221.40

221.20

221.00

221.00

221.60

221.00

221.20

*********here = value missing were a noise is visible on graph

221.20

221.00

Now,

I wrote the generated IP address in to a client programm (In the tool- named processing.org )

Here is my client code

```
import processing.net.*;

Client c;
String input;
int data[];
int posx;
void setup() 
{
size(1000, 500);
background(204);
stroke(0);
frameRate(5); // Slow it down a little
// Connect to the server's IP address and port
c = new Client(this, "192.168.23.2", 3000); // Replace with your server's IP    
      and port
posx =2;
data = new int[3];
}

void draw() 
{
posx++;  

// Receive data from server
if (c.available() > 0) {
input = c.readString();
input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("\n")); // Only up to the newline
println(input);
data[0]=data[1];

data[1] = int(input); // Split values into an array

// Draw line using received coords
stroke(0);
line(posx-1, data[0]+10, posx, data[1]+10);

  }
 }
```

My results after running the following programm:

Server sending the data and client receiving  the data wirelessly- its all fine 
I am able to see the output signal which I am expecting. i.e., when my sensor is in rest position the output must be straight line and if I stretch my sensor the voltage signal must increase- Iam able to see all these. But,

here is a small problem

There is a noise coming out from the output signal (please have a look in to the following picture.)
[Noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S1rV.png)

So my problem is even when the sensor is in rest position- with out any stretch- there is peak coming out.

please help me

Comment: Please format your code first.

Comment: First of all the code smell like [tag:arduino] and anyway is OT for SO. Something related to HW or at least to signal digital filters.

Comment: This is not C code! Get the language correct.